# How do I adjust the time between offsets when using Follow Path?

Tags: animation, constraints

I'm trying to model an orbit, so I want to sweep out the same area at one end as the other. To this end, I've done the needed calculations and determined the required offset. The perihelion isn't right, but looks acceptable, but the aphelion doesn't work at all. The orbital speed is constant, not varying.

The circle is just there to mark the outer edge of the life zone.

[image]

Comment: Is there a reason you are animating the _Offset_ on the object instead of animating the _Evaluated Time_ on the curve to fit your needs? And what exactly do you want? You have created a result but it is not perfect - I would say you have to tweak the keyframes to get the desired motion. Should we finetune your settings by what we assume you want it to be? Because I don't know in which way the aphelion "doesn't work at all", I can see no glitches, no freezing or whatever issue so we lack information what you consider "working". It might also help to delete the doubled vertices of the orbit.

Comment: the speed is varying but the difference is small, why don't you remove the Generator modifier, the Offset keyframes, and only use the curve Evaluation Time for example?

Comment: @moonboots Oh yeah, _Evaluation Time_, not _Evaluated Time_. My bad.

Comment: Because I've never heard of that method before. How do I use Evaluation Time to alter speed? And what's the Generator modifier?

Answer (score 1):

Here you are animating the planet with 2 methods: the curve *Generator* modifier and the *Offset* value of the planet *Follow Path* constraint. It makes the speed a bit hard to control. It would be simpler if you chose only one method, the planet *Offset* or the curve *Evaluation Time*.

So first thing, remove the *Generator* modifier in the *Graph Editor*. It has been created when you clicked on the *Animate Path* button of the *Follow Path* constraint:

[image]

Now set the keyframes of the planet *Offset*, or remove them and instead keyframe the *Evaluation Time* of the curve:

[image]

File: [image]

Comment: And now the planet doesn't move at all. If it matters, I'm currently using Blender 3.4.1.

The current file:
[<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=0W8dKydE" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/0W8dKydE/)

Comment: As shown in the second image, you need to keyframe the curve Evaluation Time

Comment: That's the problem, I did. The updated file should include the keyframes.

Comment: No I don't see any keyframe in the shared file

Comment: This one has keyframes. I just checked.
[<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=DmwevygX" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/DmwevygX/)

Comment: I don't see any keyframe on the Evaluation Time, for the moment you have locrotscale keyframes, you need to put some keyframe on the Evaluation Time: Put the mouse cursor on the value and press "i", move the timeline playhead, change the value and press "i" again

Comment: Download the file (see my edit)

Comment: Much better. Now I just need to figure out why the planet goes into retrograde between the fourth and fifth keyframes. [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=59Ee0q4M" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/59Ee0q4M/)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148920/discussion-between-whitewings-and-moonboots).

Comment: You're sharing the exact same file, please share the one where you've put some keyframes on the Evaluation Time

Comment: Here's the update. I added another keyframe, but the planet still goes into retrograde after the second-to-last.[<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=2kDxW2Yd" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/2kDxW2Yd/)

Comment: because you go from Evaluation Time 1653.8 to 171.285, so it goes back

Comment: Thank you very much, the planet finally moves the right way. Now I just need to smooth out the speed changes.

Comment: To change the interpolation mode, press T in the Dope Sheet and choose Bezier instead of Linear (or Key panel > Interpolation mode >Bezier)